# Django url call in ajax success innerhtml

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have the below code,

```
$.ajax({
                url: '{% url "load" %}',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                   
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    const data = response.fs
                    content_container.innerHTML = ""
                    data.map(full => {
                        content_container.innerHTML += `<a href="{%url 'business_sale_cust' id=${full.id} btype=${full.interested %}}">
                                                        <div class="border border-success mt-2 pl-2">
                                                          
                                                            <h3>${full.companyName}</h3>
                                                            <p>${full.inputEmail}</p>
                                                            
                                                        </div></a>`
                    })
```

but getting error with <a href="{%url 'business_sale_cust' id=${full.id} btype=${full.interested %}}.

please let me know how to pass the parameter id and interested with url.

Let me know how to pass the django url within ajax innerhtml.

Comment: {% url    // try put  space after %

Comment: better try pass the full url from your views.py itself then you can use it directly.

Comment: it displays list items, each item had unique id and btype value, based on that it will redirect to resp html page.